# Find the value of $X$ to equal a percentage of a defined number

Tags: percentages

I'm presented with the problem below, where $X$ and $Y$ are unknown. 
$$\begin{cases}X - 100,000 = Y\\(Y/X) \cdot 100 = 25\end{cases}$$
Is there any formula to figure out the value of $X$?

Comment: Plug in $X-100,000$ instead of $Y $ in your second equation and solve for $X $.Then go back to the first equation and plug in the value of $X $ to obtain $Y $.

Comment: If you mean that $Y$ should be $25\%$ of $X$, then write either $(Y/X)\cdot 100 = 25$ or $(Y/X) = 25\%$, but not both. Remember, $25\%$ means $25/100$.

Comment: @MPW thank you, I have corrected the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We substitute $Y$ by $X-100,000$ in the second equation

We have $$\frac{X-100,000}{X}=\frac{25}{100}$$

Multiplying X on both sides
$$X-100,000=\frac{25}{100}X$$

or 
$$\frac{75}{100}X=100,000$$

or
$$X=100,000\frac{100}{75}\approx 133,333.33
$$

Finally , $Y=X-100,000\approx 133,333.33-100,000\approx 33,333.33$

Comment: You don't have to guess. If $X$ satisfies those equations, then it **is** nonzero.

Comment: I think I understand what you're doing here, however, it is not coming out to the answer that I'm expecting. I'm expecting $X$ to be somewhere around 133,500. In that way, $Y$ is at least 25% of $X$. Does that make sense?

Comment: It seems that the question was edited. Before it was $$\begin{cases}X - 100,000 = Y\\(Y/X) \cdot 100 = 25\%\end{cases}$$

Comment: My apologies, yes I did edit the question.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you!